# How to convert a vCard into a CNContact

Tags: ios, swift, vcf-vcard, cncontact

I used this piece of code:

```
 var vcard = NSData()
 let usersContact = CNMutableContact()
 do {
     try vcard = CNContactVCardSerialization.dataWithContacts([usersContact])
 } catch {
     print("Error \(error)")
 }
```

to convert a CNMutableContact into a vCard which seems to be working.
When I try to convert the vCard back however using this (in another viewController using a segue to send the data which I'm pretty confident is working):

```
var vCardSFR = NSData()
var usersContact = CNContact()
....more code....
do {
    try usersContact = CNContactVCardSerialization.contactsWithData(vCardSFR)


} catch {
    print("Error \(error)")
}
```

but I get an error saying it cannot cannot assign value of type [AnyObject] to type CNContact.
So then I try initializing CNContact this way:

```
var usersContact = [CNContact()]
```

but then I get an error saying cannot assign value of type [AnyObject] to type [CNContact].
I'm think there's a very simple solution to this however I don't know what it might be.
I've been using this to get my code for the vCards:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContactVCardSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CNContactVCardSerialization/contactsWithData:error:

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used

```
var usersContact = []
do {
    try usersContact = CNContactVCardSerialization.contactsWithData(vCardSFR)


} catch {
    print("Error \(error)")
}
```

and then

```
var contact = usersContact[0] as! CNContact
```